# PHP: testing two double-variables gives different result without changing the variables

Tags: php, linux, variables, cgi, embedding

in my code i have two double values. Lets call them `$a` and `$b`. now I want to test which one of them is larger, so I wrote the following:

```
print ($a > $b ? "larger\n" : "smaller\n");
print ($a > $b ? "larger\n" : "smaller\n");
```

strangely the result is

```
larger
smaller
```

does anybody encountered a similar problem before? This problem only appears on our embedded linux system using php-cgi.

Thanks for your answers and advices.

Here is the whole code: I need to decode a hex value into a decimal value regarding the sign and eventually useng numbers larger than the integer-size

```
function decodeInteger($datahex)
{
    // ignore non hex characters
    $hex = preg_replace('/[^0-9A-Fa-f]/', '', $datahex);

    // converted decimal value as double:
    $dec = hexdec($hex) * 1.0;

    // maximum decimal value based on length of hex + 1:
    //   number of bits in hex number is 8 bits for each 2 hex-characters -> max = 2^n
    //   use 'pow(2.0,n)' since '1 << n' and 'pow(2,n)' is only for integers and therefore limited to integer size.
    $max = pow(2.0, 4 * (strlen($hex) + (strlen($hex) % 2)));

    // complement = maximum - converted hex:
    $_dec = $max - $dec;


    print ($dec > $_dec ? "larger\n" : "smaller\n");
    print ($dec > $_dec ? "larger\n" : "smaller\n");

    // if dec value is larger than its complement we have a negative value (first bit is set)
    return $dec > $_dec ? -$_dec : $dec;
}
```

Comment: What value do you pass to the function to get the contradictory results?

Comment: '00000000', '00000fdf', '00000efa', etc.

Comment: My guess (and this is totally a guess) is that you're losing precision with your two variables being float.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. My first suggestion would be to try and repro your bug in a brand new script on your server. Figure out what it takes to obtain the undesired output.

Answer (score 1):

Please run

```
var_dump($dec); var_dump($_dec); var_dump($dec); var_dump($_dec);
print ($dec > $_dec ? "larger\n" : "smaller\n");

var_dump($dec); var_dump($_dec); var_dump($dec); var_dump($_dec);
print ($dec > $_dec ? "larger\n" : "smaller\n");
```

and post the output here. (sorry for posting this as an answer, but my Stackoverflow Reputation does not allow for comments, yet)